# SpringBoot @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was recently going through `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation in Spring Boot and got stuck in a issue.

Sample is a bean class.

```java
package com.hobby.readinglist.bean;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
public class Sample {

    String id;
    String name;
    String isbn;
    String author;
    String descrip_tion;

    void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    void setIsbn(String isbn)
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        this.author = author;
    }
    void setDescription(String descrip_tion)
    {
        this.descrip_tion = descrip_tion;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return descrip_tion;
    }
}
```

`application.properties` file

```
sample.id=1
sample.name=The Art of Travelling
sample.author=Bishop Rude
sample.isbn=12-3425-332
sample.description=A travelling book
```

In the above code, kindly refer the `setDescription` and `getDescription` method. When I run the code the data is injecting fine from the properties file in the bean fields.

But if I change the getter method name of Description to `getDescrip_tion()` and if I run the code, then I am getting the below error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'sample' to com.hobby.readinglist.bean.Sample:

    Property: sample.descrip-tion
    Value: "A travelling book"
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 12:20
    Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No setter found for property: descrip-tion

Action:
```

The bean class after changing the `getDescription` method.

```java
package com.hobby.readinglist.bean;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
public class Sample {

    String id;
    String name;
    String isbn;
    String author;
    String descrip_tion;

    void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    void setIsbn(String isbn)
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        this.author = author;
    }
    void setDescription(String descrip_tion)
    {
        this.descrip_tion = descrip_tion;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getDescrip_tion() {
        return descrip_tion;
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand this as when Spring does the setter injection then it will refer to setter method only, but here getter method is also getting referred. If I change from `getDescrip_tion()` to `getDescription()` then it works fine.

Comment: 1. As long "description" is the source name (from properties), the bean mechanism will of course look for get/setDescription. 2. The Java Bean convention demands a getter and a setter with same naming rules. 3. Probably, the error message demanding a setter, when the setter exists, could be a glitch or purposely (as the bean does not follow the convention) in Spring or 3rd party lib.

Comment: Why did you rename the getter but not the setter?

Comment: it is mentioned that @ConfigurationProperties can inject even if the name of the instance field is having '-' ,'_' in between its name. For eg:- in the property file we can have the name as 'description' and in instance field we can have name as descripti_on, then also the annotation will inject the value.  Initially when the name was description, I had created the method setDescription, after changing the name to descrip_tion, I had added one getter method to access it in another class., hence the name is different.